# Limit involving hypergeometric function.

Tags: limits, hypergeometric-function

I'm trying to prove a limit involving a Hypergeometric function, which seems to hold numerically, but I'm stuck. I have the following function:

$
f(A,B)=\frac{2A\pi ^{5/2} (-1)^B}{{\left(A!\right)^2 B!}}\,_{4}\tilde F_3\left[{{\frac12,\,1-A,\,1-A,\,1-B}\atop{\frac12-A,\,\frac12-A,\,\frac12-B}};1\right]
$

where $A$ and $B$ are positive integers and ${}_4\tilde F_3$ is a [regularized Hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedHypergeometricFunction.html). We have that $0\leq f(A,B)\leq1$.

I have a numerical hunch that $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}f(Am,Bm)=1 - \frac{B}{4A}$ for $A\geq B$.
I would *love* to show this appropriately and some day to find the limit in case $A<B$.

So far I have tried to expand $f$ by using hypergeometric identities, but I'm trying blindly, I'm not sure what to do.

EDIT: I have turned the case $A=B$ into a continued fraction problem, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156667/on-the-asymptotics-of-a-continued-fraction).