# On the asymptotics of a continued fraction

Tags: limits, continued-fractions

I know the coefficients of the continued fraction representation of a function that diverges like $O(\sqrt{x})$, where the $a_k$ depend on $x$,

$
f(x)=1+a_0/\left(1+\underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty }{K}}\frac{-a_k}{a_k+1}\right)=1+\frac{\displaystyle{a_0}}{\displaystyle{1-\frac{a_1}{(1+a_1)-\displaystyle\frac{a_2}{(1+a_2)-\displaystyle\frac{a_3}{\dots}}}}}
$

Is there a way of computing $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$? Is *should* be $\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$.

EDIT: For completeness, $a_k=\frac{\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right) (k-2 x+1)^3}{(k+1) \left(k-2 x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^3}$.

Comment: The CF [represents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\prod_{k=0}^{n}a_k$ which *diverges* (if $2x\notin\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$). No $f(x)$ to talk about.